# How to solve the Logcat error in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I create one application which send the email. but when i click on send button
 following error occure.i don't know meaning of this error.
Pls help me how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance.

```
[2012-02-17 17:53:35 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-02-17 17:53:36 - Emulator] destroyOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
[2012-02-17 17:53:36 - Emulator] createOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
[2012-02-17 17:53:36 - Emulator] repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show us some code where this is happening.

Comment: Are you using openGL in your application??

Comment: @Creator: Yes! But how to solve this?

Comment: @sandiparmal: Then this is a duplicate of that question and this question needs to be closed.

Comment: Here i got my answer..... [This link solve this problem][1]...

Enjoy...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576996/how-do-i-run-the-android-emulator-after-a-build