# repaintOpenGLDisplay on Android emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm writing to get some help with the following error, that i get every time i add Gpu support to my emulator(API versions >= 7,I didn't checked lower ones, currently using 4.0.3):

`[2012-05-05 20:44:02 - Emulator] repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!`

I tried to search SO but only found topics like: [How to solve the Logcat error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328379/how-to-solve-the-following-error-in-android) that didn't helped me much.

My OS is Windows7 32bit, and don't know how could I do fix like: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28565 - event i'm not sure if this works.

I have tried few times to reinstall eclipse ver 3.7, ADTr18 and Android SDK but problem still happens.

Any clue how to fix this? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, turn off GPU emulation in the AVD profile/Aindroid Virtual Device

Comment: i know that is solution to not show error, but how to fix this with to be able to work with openGl? ?