# How do I run the Android Emulator after a Build?

Tags: opengl, android-emulator, ubuntu-10.04, android-build

So I have download the source code successfully, built it successfully, and can run the emulator successfully. However it never boots into the actual image. Instead I look at the terminal and it gives me the following error.

```
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x2deae10
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x105 returned 1 visuals
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
destroyOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
createOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
createOpenGLSubwindow not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
repaintOpenGLDisplay not implemented for separate renderer process !!!
```

I am running Ubuntu 10.04, inside of Virtual Box. With 3D Acceleration enabled and at least 16GB of ram dedicated to the box.

Basically the emulator just sits there for a good while and then draws a red rectangle around the emulator window.

Comment: So you have a VM running Ubuntu in which another VM (android) is started -- and this does not work? [A shot in the dark](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html): _"Not Inside a VM - You cannot run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another virtual machine, such as a VirtualBox or VMWare-hosted virtual machine. You must run the emulator directly on your system hardware."_

Comment: Well I guess that about sums it up, and yes that is what I was doing. I guess I can still do builds at least. Thanks for the link

Comment: Disabling the acceleration is no option?

Comment: Oh I can disabled 3d Acceleration but it did not make a difference. It was running like that prior and didn't seem to change anything. I am going to test again with it off.

Comment: Ok disabling 3D acceleration did it. I am not sure what happened prior to that. Maybe I just needed to reboot the Ubuntu Virtual Machine. It is all working now. Quite perfectly actually, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Using the Android Emulator|Configuring VM Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm):

> Not Inside a VM - You cannot run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another virtual machine, such as a VirtualBox or VMWare-hosted virtual machine. You must run the emulator directly on your system hardware.

So disable 3D acceleration and it should work.

Another possible option: [setup port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp). You should be able to run the Android VM on the host system and setup listening of its adb server instance to listen to TCP connection requests. Inside the Ubuntu instance, tell adb to connect to a specific address. You'd need to setup a forwarding from it to its host somehow. If this works, you could use an accelerated Android VM instance.