# 'wglGetExtensionsStringARB' error running map application in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a map application in Android and am testing this app on Android emulator. The problem is that when I run the application it crashes with console output:

```
[2012-07-09 10:16:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I don't understand what the issue is. What is the cause of this error? And can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576996/how-do-i-run-the-android-emulator-after-a-build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, your app requires OpenGL 2.0, emulator didn't support it until recently. If so, check this  [Android OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator)